# ElasticSearch save bulk

Tags: elasticsearch

During bulk indexing in elastic search when the refresh interval is 1s and in a scenario where there are 1k records in the save bulk request and suppose 400 of these records are indexed in 1s will these 400 be visible for the remaining records?

Comment: What do you mean by "visible for the remaining records"?

Comment: Will those 400 records be visible for search?

Comment: Yes, anything that's been refreshed, even though the bulk operation is not finished, will be available for search

Comment: @val I tried save bulk with 1000 records and the 1st and the last records refer to the same document, if 1st record is visible for search than the last record should have updated it instead of creating a new document.In this case it was not updating the document whereas new document was indexed

Comment: 1st question: What's the rationale for having the same document present twice in the same bulk operation? Why not merge them? 2nd question: What was the bulk command for the first and last documents (both index or first is index and last is update)?

Comment: @Val 1.there can be a possibility of having the same document twice ,with same identifiers but different data ex:like suppose 1st document where one of the fields "status" may be PACKED and last document may have "status" as SHIPPED" 2.both Index

Comment: Then if both are "index" commands, the latter document will override the former, there's no possibility of update taking place in this case. Also what ID are you using in the first vs the last document

Comment: @Val Id are same for both the document

Comment: There you go, if you have two index commands and the IDs are the same then the second index command overrides the first one